# vbscript - How to use Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)

Tags: web-services, vbscript, asp-classic, domdocument

I have the following Classic ASP VBScript code that I have to use:

```vb
binRequest = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
Set objDomDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
bGoodXml = objDomDoc.load(binRequest)
```

This code is supposed to receive something that will transform into an xml.

I use the following code in C# to send a request with an xml to the page that contains the code listed above:

```c#
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
string postData = getXML();
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);<br/>
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
        stream.Write(data, 0, postData.Length);
}   
return "200";
```

and

```c#
private string getXML()
        {
            return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>" +
                "<MessageHeader>" +
                    "<ApplicationNo>" +
                        "1325447" +
                    "</ApplicationNo>" +
                "</MessageHeader>";
        }
```

The problem is that in the VBScript code `Request.TotalBytes` has a value (112), Request.Body contains the xml but `Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)` returns Empty and `bGoodXml` is False.
Am I doing something wrong ? Am I sending incorrect Data ? And NO, I cannot use `Request.Body` or `objDomDoc.loadXML(binRequest)`. I have to use the VBScript code that is given.

Edit:
Forgot to mention I am using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. Both of your codes worked for me fine.
First of all, Request.BinaryRead never returns `Empty` but can cause an error. It looks like there was an error suppressed by an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the code, and the value could not be assigned to **binRequest**, so you have `Empty`. The error must be related with the following.

From [Request.BinaryRead Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525710%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The BinaryRead method is used to read the raw data sent by the client
>   as part of a POST request. This method is used for low-level access to
>   this data, as opposed to, for example, using the Request.Form
>   collection to view form data sent in a POST request. **After you have
>   used BinaryRead, referring to any variable in the Request.Form
>   collection causes an error.** **Conversely, after you have referred to a
>   variable in the Request.Form collection, using BinaryWrite will cause
>   an error.** Remember, if you access a variable in the Request collection
>   without specifying which subcollection it belongs to, the Request.Form
>   collection may be searched, bringing this rule into force.

Comment: Hello Kul-Tigin. I have updated my code above to show a return statement. That statement is being hit so I presume there are no Errors in the executing code. Can you give me a sample of the code you used to send data ? Is it exactly the same code ?

Comment: Yes it is. Three lines of ASP and the C# code. Getting `112` for `Request.TotalBytes` means C# works for you too.

Comment: Maybe...but Request.ReadBytes(Request.TotalBytes) is not working. So data is being transmitted from C# (Request.Form contains what I need) maybe it is not formatted correctly ?

Comment: @PestreaRadu-Constantin It's `Request.BinaryRead` not `Request.ReadBinary` or `Request.ReadBytes`. and it's not a format-aware method, just reads raw data.

Comment: Understood. I mistyped. Can you please tell me what .NET are you using, what project did you create to test and what Visual Studio ?

Comment: I tried some variants, none worked and then I did revert to the vbscript code. It worked all of the sudden. Thank you very much for all the information to everyone, I have marked the problem resolved...unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to mark the answers as useful.

Comment: Be careful of `Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)` if it exceeds the default of 200 KB in IIS it will cause an error to occur.

Comment: @Lankymart It's not about BinaryRead only, any attempt to acccess a Request collection / method that relies on request body (e.g. .Form) will cause error if the limit exceeded.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin If you call `BinaryRead()` the `Request` object no longer has access to the built-in `Form` and `QueryString` collections. Accessing these requires some kind of custom parsing of the binary data. You are most likely to get an limit error when calling `Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)` but like you say I'm sure it's not the only time.

Answer (score 3):

[.load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reads data from a location/URL. Use [.loadXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read from a string.

**On second thought:**

You'll need to convert the SafeArray returned from .BinaryRead to a String.

**On third thought:**

Even if you post an URL, the conversion to a String that `.load` needs has to be done in the VBScript code.

Comment: I cannot change the vbscript code, only the c# code. Is there anyway to change that ? Maybe post the location of the xml file or anything else that Request.ReadBinary(Request.TotalBytes) will return a valid value for objDomDoc.load ?

Comment: I tried to post a path in the request, but Request.BinaryRead still returns nothing. I need a way to make a webservice written in C# to make a request to a vbscript page and Request.BinaryRead work.

Comment: +1 @Ekkehard.Horner [.load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can read data from SAFEARRAY of bytes, not only location/URL, have a look at `xmlSource[in]` description. And @PestreaRadu-Constantin both of your codes just worked for me. I have a theory about the issue, I will answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can simply do this:

```
objDomDoc.load Request
```

Where `objDomDoc` is an instance of `MSXML2.DOMDOCUMENT` and `Request` is the ASP classic's built-in request object.