# Unable to upload file in Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to upload file from javascript to Classic ASP.

I have written Javascript in Classic ASP page as below.

```
    function SendMessage(){

        frmObj=window.document.frmContact;
        strFName = frmObj.firstname.value;
        strLName = frmObj.lastname.value;
        strName = strFName + ' ' + strLName;
        strEmail = frmObj.email.value;
        strMessage = frmObj.message.value;
        
        var data = new FormData();
        for(var k = 1; k < 9; k++){
            fileName = "upload" + k;
            file = document.getElementById(fileName).files;
            if (file.length!=0){
                strFileName = file[0].name;
                data.append('image', file[0], strFileName);
            }
        }
        
        strURL = 'xml_SendContactWithImage.asp?';
        strURL = strURL + "Name=" + encodeURIComponent(strName);
        strURL = strURL + "&EMail=" + encodeURIComponent(strEmail);
        strURL = strURL + "&Message=" + encodeURIComponent(strMessage);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', strURL , true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=MyBoundary');
        xhr.send(data);
        
        xhr.onload = function () {

            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var strResponse = xhr.responseText;
                if( strResponse.indexOf('Your information has been successfully delivered to OFONJ.com')>-1){
                    var strResponse = xhr.responseText;
                    divErrorMsgContact.innerHTML = '<p><font color="FDB100">' + strResponse + '</font></p>';
                    frmObj.firstname.value = '';
                    frmObj.lastname.value = '';
                    frmObj.email.value = '';
                    frmObj.message.value = '';
                    divFiles.innerHTML = strDivFileHTML;
                }else{
                    var strResponse = xhr.responseText;
                    divErrorMsgContact.innerHTML = '<p><font color="Red">' + strResponse + '</font></p>';
                }
            }else{

                debugger
                var strResponse = xhr.responseText;
                divErrorMsgContact.innerHTML = '<p><font color="Red">' + strResponse + '</font></p>';
            }
        };
    }
```

**Backend Code**

```
    Dim uploadsDirVar
    uploadsDirVar = Server.MapPath("/upload/temp")
    'uploadsDirVar = Server.MapPath("/ofonj/upload/temp")
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey, increment
    Dim arrFiles(2)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    
    Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
    
    Upload.SaveVirtual("/upload/temp")
    
    increment = 0
    SaveFiles = "<B>Files uploaded:</B> "
    
    For Each File in Upload.Files
       If File.ImageType = "UNKNOWN" Then
          SaveFiles = SaveFiles & File.Path & " is not an image"
        Else
          arrFiles(increment) = File.Path
          increment = increment + 1
       End If
    Next
```

I am getting below error while uploading file.

```
There were errors in sending your message. Please try again later. 
(Error: 006~ASP 0208~Cannot use generic Request collection~Cannot use the generic Request collection after calling BinaryRead.)
```

Comment: This is not VB.Net, Classic ASP uses active scripting languages like VBScript and JScript, this appears to be VBScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vbscript - How to use Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470598/vbscript-how-to-use-request-binaryreadrequest-totalbytes). See the bold description in the accepted answer.

Comment: Once you call `Request.BinaryRead` you can no longer access the in-built `Request.Form` collection. That’s why component’s like `Persits.Upload` provide their own collections for accessing this data. See the [Official Documentation](http://aspupload.com/object_upload.html#Form) for how to use their `Form` object to access your form values.

Comment: Also from the link from @user692942: _Remember, if you access a variable in the Request collection without specifying which subcollection it belongs to, the Request.Form collection may be searched, bringing this rule into force._ If you need values from the querystring, you need to access as `Request.Querystring("... ")` and not as `Request("...")`

Comment: User @user69294 answer is correct, this not a duplicate of the answer selected.